# Access one page on localhost via two urls

Tags: php, nginx, dns, webserver, config

I need help to make run the same localhost page on two urls.

I have nginx running on my localhost configured so that my project urls looks like this: `http://project.loc`. I need it to be working as it is now, plus is has to run on `localhost/project.loc`, or `127.0.0.1/project.loc` also, without redirect. Is such thing possible? I've got it working so when I go to the `localhost/project.loc`, it redirects me to the `http://project.loc`. This is my server config:

```
    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;

            location ~ ^/(?<project>[^/]+)(?<rest>.*) {
                    resolver 127.0.0.1;
                    proxy_pass http://$project$rest;
            }
    }

    server {
            # fix for ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
            sendfile off;

            listen 80;

            client_max_body_size 700M;

            server_name ~^(.*?([^.]*)?\.?([^.]*)\.loc)$;

            set $server_root /Users/username/Development/php;

            if (-e $server_root/$2.loc) {
                    set $domain $2.loc;
            }

            if (-e $server_root/$2.loc) {
                    set $domain $2.loc;
            }

            if (-e $server_root/$2.$3.loc) {
                    set $domain $2.$3.loc;
            }

            if (-e $server_root/$1) {
                    set $domain $1;
            }

            if (-e $server_root/$domain/web) {
                    set $root $server_root/$domain/web;
            }

            if (-e $server_root/$domain/www) {
                    set $root $server_root/$domain/www;
            }

            if (-e $server_root/$domain/public) {
                    set $root $server_root/$domain/public;
            }

            if (-e $server_root/$domain/web/www) {
                    set $root $server_root/$domain/web/www;
            }

            root $root;

            index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

            error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx.log;
            access_log on;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri = 404;
                    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    fastcgi_connect_timeout 1800;
                    fastcgi_send_timeout 1800;
                    fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
                    fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
                    fastcgi_buffers 8 512k;
                    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
                    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 512k;
            }

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                    autoindex on;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Serving every request on different URL has to be done with `http` redirecting headers. Why you don't want  to use `http` redirecting headers ?